# How does SSIS know which variable in an OnVariableValueChanged Event?

Tags: ssis, eventhandler

OK, I understand all the whys and wherefores of how to create variables in ssis and that the raise_change_event must be set for the event handler to work.  And, I have a SQL task written to insert a record into the SysSSISLog when the event fires.

However, despite all my digging, I can't find where/how the event handle knows WHICH variable changed.

So, it appears to me if you have multiple variables, and anyone of them changes, then the OnVariableValueChange event would fire.  This makes no sense and suggests to me that I am missing something incredibly simple.

Could someone please enlighten me?   THanks...

Comment: I can't find my research notes on the subject but the summary was "you think `OnVariableValueChanged` event is going to be useful but it's totally not."

Answer (score 0):

When the value of a variable is changed, the OnVariableValueChangedEvent event will only fire if the RaiseChangedEvent property of that variable is set to true (which is false by default).  One thing to keep in mind, if the variable contains an expression that relies on another variable, this event will only be raised if the RaiseChangedEvent property of the dependent variable is set to true, and the raised event will only correspond to the dependent variable.